# Illogical Land Surface Temperature value from Landsat 8 Level 2 Collection 2 Tier 1

Tags: google-earth-engine, temperature, landsat

We have been working on research about urban heat using Land Surface Temperature (LST) in Google Earth Engine. We analyzed the LST pattern in 2021 by using Landsat 8 Level 2 Collection 2 Tier 1. However, after finding out the results it startled us that the LST value (temperature) is very high, higher than what could be deemed rational or realistic (max value >65 degrees celsius, min value 33 degrees celsius). In 2021, the urban temperature in the case study has only ever reached up to 35 degrees celsius empirically.

So with this, is there anything wrong that we did in the analysis or is there any step or calculation that we might have missed? Or is it just the data that has led to the irrational result of the LST value?

Link to the code for you to check what's wrong:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/cb40b4e01b65ac8ea905510375613106

I tried to obtain temperature values of LST from Landsat 8 Collection 2 Level 2 series, but the results that I obtained are irrational of which the LST values are very high (> 65-degree celsius) which does not support life